# How to make a <p><button class="button">Button</button></p> direct to a link on click

Tags: html, button

I've been writing some HTML code to develop a website. I want to have some buttons link to other parts of the page. The button is in a "Meet the Team" style. Here is the code:

```
<div class="column">
<div class="card">
 <div class="container">
  <img src="button1.png" alt="Button" style="width:100%">
    <div class="centered"><h1> Lorem Ipsum </h1></div>
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
    elit.</p>
    <p><button class="button">Button</a></button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to get it to link to a page but I can't find anything (I'm new to HTML). Maybe one of you can help? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: The `button` element is not really the right tool for the job here. Use `a` and style it like a button. See the linked duplicate for suggestions on how you can do this. By using `button` you break expected behaviors e.g : right click giving contextual menus and middle (scroll wheel) click opening in new window.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to link other pages style `a` tag looks like button:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Click me</a>
```

Alternatives:

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'" type="button">
    www.example.com
</button>
```

Or

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Google" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but Is there any way I can still keep the style and look of the original button?

Comment: Note that nesting a `button` in an `a` tag is [invalid html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: So how would I still keep the style of the button but not nest the <button> in a <a> tag, and still make it link to a .html file on click?

Comment: '<a  class="button" href="//www.google.com">Button</a>'`<style>.button{
   background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}</style>`

Answer (score -1):

Your `button` tag is not properly formatted, the `</a>` will break your html code.
All you have to do is just pass `href` attribute to `button`.

```
 <p><button type="button" class="button" href="team-page.html">Button</button></p>
```

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/ is a very good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will go for anchor tag instead then give it a button style.